# Box2d - AndEngine

Tags: box2d, andengine

How can I get sprite associated with body in andengine gles2?
When bodies collide, I can get associated bodies but how can I get sprites associated with those bodies.

Please help me, I m new to andengine and box2d.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Body that body let you set some extra data, like this:

```
myBody.setUserData( "Monster" ); //to set a String
myBody.setUserData( 333 ); //to set a number
myBody.setUserData( new MyData() ); //to set other Object
```

In fact this method accepts anything because it require a Object element.
So you can create your own class to handle which sprite/entity is associated to that body, like this:

```
class BodyData{
    public IEntity mEntity;
    public String mName;

    public BodyData(String pName, pEntity){
        mEntity = pEntity;
        mName = pName;
    }
}
```

Then when you create your body and connect to a sprite you can do something like this:

```
myPlayerBody.setUserData( new BodyData("Player", myPlayerSprite ));
```

And when detecting the collide:

```
mPhysicsWorld.setContactListener( 
    new ContactListener(){
        public void beginContact(Contact contact){
            final Fixture mB1 = contact.getFixtureA();
            final Fixture mB2 = contact.getFixtureB();

            if(mB2.getBody().getUserData() != null && mB1.getBody().getUserData() != null){
                final BodyData mBD1 = (BodyData)mB1.getBody().getUserData();
                final BodyData mBD2 = (BodyData)mB2.getBody().getUserData();
                Sprite mSprite1 = (Sprite) mBD1.mEntity;
                Sprite mSprite2 = (Sprite) mBD2.mEntity;
                // Do whatever you want to do with the sprites
            }
        }
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {   
        }
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {   
        }
        public void postSolve(Contact contact,
                ContactImpulse impulse) {
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to register a `PhysicConnector` so you can connect a sprite to a body:

```
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprite, body, true, true));
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Body variable in above Body bodyname;
    //associate body with the sprite
    body=PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physics_world, sprite_name, BodyType.DynamicBody, fixturedefinition);
```

Here in the last line fixture definition is to be defined as per your choice.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Body set the UserData to you sprite/entity like this:

```
yourBody.setUserData(yourSprite);
```

In the physic events you can get the sprite using:

```
public void beginContact(final Contact contact) {
    final Body bA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    final Body bB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    final Object oA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
    final Object oB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();
    final Sprite spriteA = (Sprite)oA;
    final Sprite spriteB = (Sprite)oB;
}
```